# How can I extend AWS SNS Maximum number of recipients per message more than 50?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

Can anyone confirm how to extend AWS email recipient max count from 50 to 200? We got an issue in production which is breaking prod email into two different emails. How can I accommodate all the emails in a single email? Here is the document that displays Maximum number of recipients per message is 50. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/quotas.html

Comment: It says clearly on the page you linked that this limit is not adjustable. You might reach out to your AWS account rep about it if you find that to be unacceptable.

Comment: Why can't you thread/parallel process this?  Or even if it's serialized, send them out in batches of 50?

Comment: We are trying to keep all the 75 recipients in the same email rather creating multiple batch and dividing the recipient list in to more than one email. Any idea how to do it?